# Meaning of “up to something”

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't get this specifically: When some people are up to something.

For example: **We’re up to the murder.**

It occurs in this passage from *The Lost Girl: A Fear Street Novel*
by R. L. Stine:

> “You don’t mind if I clean my jewelry while you work, do you?” Mom asked. She sat down at the other end of the table and started pulling rings and earrings out of the box.
>      “**We’re up to the murder**,” Gabe said, reaching for a blank sheet of paper. “What if we make it so the player can choose his victim?” Diego asked.
>      “You know. Like who should Macbeth kill first? Maybe we give him an automatic rifle, and he runs through the castle—”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Gabe and Diego are writing a story, or planning a role-playing game.  They are up to, *i.e.* they have reached, the point in the plot where the murder belongs.

While climbing a mountain you might say “I am up to the treeline.”  Then *up to* becomes a general metaphor for progress.

Note that, in the sentence that bothers you, *murder* is a noun not a verb.